Estimating asset correlation coefficient using CDS data and default probability
I have a CDS dataset with several instruments belonging to different sectors, par mid spread values and probability of default (recorded daily 2009-2023).
I want to take all the firms within one specific sector and estimate asset correlation coefficient using MLE and MoM. Any ideas where I should begin with or any specific structure I should create like assigning ratings to instruments based on average PDs etc.

Can you please clarify what you mean by asset correlation?

X_{it} = S_t √ρ + Z_{it} √(1 - ρ)
In this case, I meant using Vasicek model and S is the systematic risk and Z defines the idiosyncratic risk. Here asset correlation is rho (ρ). I need to estimate rho defining the correlation between the asset and the systematic risk. Keeping systematic risk heterogenous for all the instruments and for that I already have different probability of default value for each instrument.
